# wifi doesn't work but lan does

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

This is a small network of a small hotel. The equipment is very simple and there are no manageable devices (except the router, of course). So I checked the connection with my ISP and it seems perfectly fine. No problems with convertor or fiber cable.

While I was checking my network, I noticed something interesting. While I connected to the switch via cable, I got a perfect Internet connection, with stable ping to 8.8.8.8.  But when I try to ping my router while connected via WiFi, it doesn't even ping it.  I restart the router and AP and it starts working for awhile, but after some time, the same situation appears.

I checked AP's and router.

What did I miss that I should check?

Comment: Does the router have any accessible logs? Maybe firmware updates for the router.

Comment: I did check log files , nothing strange appears only arp messages...